# To put into or strike an agreement

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or paraphrase which fits the meaning of two people striking an agreement that is suitable to both.

For example, I could say that two countries have struck an agreement with respect to their own interests.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reached an accord* might work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't particularly like it, but you could say such an agreement created *a win-win situation*.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. It does fit though :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can say:

> The two countries have struck an agreement that benefits both.

Comment: That has some potential. One could use mutual benefit but I'm not sure how I'd rephrase that.